# Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type (list of ints contains int)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a method that receives a string array. I then turn it into a List of ints. Finally I am creating an IQueryable where I want to return results that match the IDs in an associated table.

```
public myMethod(string[] locationRoleids){
IQueryable<equipment> result = DbContext.equipment.Where(e => !e.deleted);
List<int> locationRoleIdList = locationRoleIds.Select(id => int.Parse(id)).ToList();
result = result.Where(e => locationRoleIdList.Contains(e.eqp_ast_equipment_to_location.Any(el => el.eqp_equipment_location_role_id)));
```

I'm getting an error on

```
el.eqp_equipment_location_role_id
```

stating "Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type"

eqp_equipment_location_role_id is an int and i'm checking if a list of ints contain that number. I don't understand what the problem is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't `eqp_equipment_location_role_id` return a `bool` (since it is an `Any`), but the name suggests that it is an `int`, or at least not a `bool`.

Comment: Furthermore `Contains` checks for an *element*, not for a collection, or `bool` itself (yes a `bool` *can* be an element), but this is probably *not* what you intedd.

Comment: Right now it is however hard to solve the problem. What is `eqp_ast_equipment_to_location`? Can you share your (relevant) class definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Contains` takes a value rather than a lambda. Therefore, `e.eqp_ast_equipment_to_location.Any(el => el.eqp_equipment_location_role_id)` isn't a valid item of type `int`.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Contains__0_

Maybe:

```
result = result.Where(e => e.eqp_ast_equipment_to_location.Any(el => locationRoleIdList.Contains(el.eqp_equipment_location_role_id)));
```

is nearer what was intended?

Comment: Yes that is what I intended. Thanks.